# Creating shapefile from selection - remove from map

Tags: python, arcpy, arcmap

I am iterating over a shapefile and creating a new shape from each row. I will be creating several thousand individual shapes and do not want to inundate my TOC with that many layers (I bet ArcMap would crash if I did). Using the code below, each shape is added after being created. How could I remove the shape from the TOC after being created? I tried deleting the tempPoly variable but that did not do the trick.

```
polys = arcpy.SearchCursor(shapefile) #recall the cursor
for poly in polys: 
    print('starting at '+str(poly.FID))
    whereClause = '"FID" = ' + str(poly.FID     ) # Create a clause to select only the current record
    tempPoly=arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(shapefile,tempFilesPath,"tempPoly"+str(poly.FID),whereClause)
```

I am not working in a dataframe and am in the data view not the layout view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have three options here:

1. Un-check the **Add results of geoprocessing  operations to display** check box (Geoprocessing menu>Geoprocessing Options)
2. By code, use the arcpy [`RemoveLayer()`](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00s300000039000000) method.
3. Also by code, use the arcpy [`Delete` (Data Management)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000052000000) Geoprocessing function to remove the layer by name.

Answer (score 1):

Are these polygons features (it appears they are)?  Is there a unique field of type "Text" (something other than FID)?

If so, you could also just use the [Split_Analysis](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Split/000800000006000000/) tool, and use the featureclass as both the input features and split features, the "Text" field as the split field, and then define your target workspace.